# Function for capturing images from a webcam using openCV works only the first time called

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am new to OpenCV and actually programming in general. I am trying to write a function that will capture a single image from my camera every time it is called. I wrote this function but it only works the first time it is called. I kind of jumped in over my head but now I am hooked and have to figure this problem out.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int faceCnt = 1;
    faceCnt = captureFace(faceCnt);
    cout << faceCnt << endl;
    if(faceCnt == -1)
             cout << "A problem has occured << endl;
    faceCnt = captureFace(faceCnt);
    cout << faceCnt << endl;
    if(faceCnt == -1)
             cout << "A problem has occured << endl;
    return 0;
}
int captureFace(int cnt){
    Mat temp;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened())  //Check to see if capture was successful
            return -1;
    cap >> temp;
    cap.release();
    char numstr[21]; // enough to hold all numbers up to 64-bits
    sprintf(numstr, "%d", cnt);
    string location = "faces/sub";
    string fileType = ".jpg";
    string result = location + numstr + fileType;
    imwrite(result, temp);
    cout << result << endl;
    cnt++;
    if(cap.isOpened())
       return -1;
    return cnt;
}
```

The out put from the console:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd2
faces/sub1.jpg
2HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Bad file descriptor
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor

faces/sub2.jpg
3
```

Looking at some other answers for the errors I got, I found that they supposedly didn't really matter(although I don't know if I believe it). I am using a Logitech C270 for my camera and I am running xubuntu 13.10.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Try with  cap.release()  after imwrite()

Comment: @Haris I tried moving cap.release() to several places including after imwrite() to no avail.

Comment: Maybe the camera need some time before you can open it again. Try adding a `sleep(1);` after the `cap.release();`

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Ok so interestingly enough a sleep function did nothing...There was no difference between having the sleep function or not. No matter what I passed to it or where I had it nothing changed. I am running linux so I tried using 'usleep()', Posix threads, and writing my own sleep function. Could this mean something? Maybe I am doing something completely dumb but it complies fine.

Comment: @user3034930 under linux it is `usleep(1000*sleepTime)` the 1000 is just to translate between the unit used by windows (second) and the unit used by Linux (ms). It could be that, aside from a small pause in the programm, changes nothing. Than the error is most propably not related to initialization time issues.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Even with the conversion to ms there isn't really a noticeable pause unless huge values are passed like 10000000 ms which would be 10000 s which it definitely isn't pausing for. Is there something I could just be doing dumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that closing and opening VideoCaptures for the same webcam fails sometimes. It would probably be best to open the webcam once and reuse it.

Also you not necessarily need to call release(), that is automatically done in the destructor of VideoCapture or when calling open() again.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int faceCnt = 1;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    faceCnt = captureFace(faceCnt, cap);
    cout << faceCnt << endl;
    if(faceCnt == -1)
             cout << "A problem has occured << endl;
    faceCnt = captureFace(faceCnt, cap);
    cout << faceCnt << endl;
    if(faceCnt == -1)
             cout << "A problem has occured << endl;
    return 0;
}

int captureFace(int cnt, VideoCapture& cap){
    Mat temp;
    if(!cap.isOpened())  //Check to see if capture was successful
            return -1;
    cap >> temp;
    char numstr[21]; // enough to hold all numbers up to 64-bits
    sprintf(numstr, "%d", cnt);
    string location = "faces/sub";
    string fileType = ".jpg";
    string result = location + numstr + fileType;
    imwrite(result, temp);
    cout << result << endl;
    cnt++;
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick! I wasn't aware of this problem but it is good to know. Thanks!